# Which way of implemeting conditions in Entity Framework yields better performance?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

When I want to do some validation stuff on database entities, I can think of two ways:

**1: Retrive the field value and then do the calculations in the application:**

```
if (dbContext.Coupons.Where(c=> c.Id == couponId).Select(c=> c.ExpirationDate).Single() <= DateTime.Now)
```

**2: Do the calculations in the query (in 'Select()' method) and then retrive the result:**

```
if (dbContext.Coupons.Where(c=> c.Id == couponId).Select(c=> c.ExpirationDate <= DateTime.Now).Single())
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be much faster, if you just made a benchmark with some data? Then you would know which one is better, performance wise

Comment: If your `couponId` is primary key (well, according your where->select->single - it is), instead of `.Where(c=> c.Id == couponId)` you can do `Coupons.Find(couponId).ExpirationDate <= DateTime.Now`.

Comment: **Race your horses** https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @SeM Find method retrives the whole row from the database and actually kills the performace.

Comment: @AmirHosseinAhmadi it depends whether your row exists in cache or not.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, every validation, filter or process do within linq or process that take value from db (SQL Query) or object.

for example :

if you have 10 datas in table and you use the second way, the app will import all data into local memory and filtered inside app.

but if you use the first way, the app only import the datas that already filtered (example only 4 datas after filter process)

if your datas is more than 10K maybe you'll see the different

Answer (score 0):

This will give you best performance.

```
if (dbContext.Coupons.Any(c => c.Id == couponId && c.ExpirationDate <= DateTime.Now))
```

Comment: What are the differences between your approach and my second approach? (They both return a boolean and do the same thing)

Comment: @AmirHosseinAhmadi Using Where () creates an iterator which adds performance impact, whereas using any () with predicate can perform its task without an iterator.

In additional, You will get an exception if your condition will find more than 1 record.

Comment: First of all, "Where()" method creates an IQueryable which is going to be translated to SQL, and in both of these two ways, we have the same generated SQL (not exactly the same, there is a slight difference). Second of all, there's definitely only 1 element in the sequence because the condition is based on the primary key.

Comment: @AmirHosseinAhmadi As far as I know, Using any() Linq is generate SQL query with exists and return true or false, so there is no require extra condition as you mention in your question.